My BMW app - where did the fan go?
In version 11/2023.50 of the My BMW app I cannot find the fan icon to remotely start heating or cooling of the car. It was there before, anyone know where it's gone?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Did you consult with your BMW dealer or go online to BMW to enquire about your My BMW app? They're more likely to have accurate info.

I had to "buy" the BMW ConnectedDrive Remote Services (free of charge) from with in the app. Restart the app and icon toolbar for Lock, unlock, lights, horn and heating are available again.
